# Graphql React - get data in react with graphql query

Tags: reactjs, graphql

I'm just starting out with graphql and React.

I have a types, resolvers, a monogoDB and mongoose schemas all working.

I have the playgoround working and can use it to make queries and mutations to update the DB.

My problem now is making queries from React and getting back the data.

My index.js is:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './components/App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';

import { ApolloClient } from "apollo-client";
import { ApolloProvider } from "react-apollo";
import { HttpLink } from 'apollo-link-http';
import { InMemoryCache } from 'apollo-cache-inmemory';

const cache = new InMemoryCache();
const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/'
})

const client = new ApolloClient({
  cache,
  link
})

ReactDOM.render(
  <ApolloProvider client={client}>
    <App />
  </ApolloProvider>
  , document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

I have a query like this in the file queries
This query works in the playground

```
import { gql } from 'apollo-boost';

export const GET_ALL_RECIPES = gql`
  query{
    getAllRecipes{
      name
      description
    }
  }
`
```

and I'm trying to get the date like:

```
import React from 'react';
import './App.css';

import { Query } from "react-apollo";
import { GET_ALL_RECIPES } from "../queries";

const App = () => (
  <div className="App">
    <h1>Home</h1>

    <Query query={GET_ALL_RECIPES}>
      {({ data, loading, error }) => {
        if (loading) return <div>Loading</div>
        if (error) return <div>Error</div>

        console.log(data)

        return (
          <p>Recipes</p>
        )

      }}
    </Query>

  </div>
)

export default App;
```

On the page it shows loading but the console.log says undefined.

Comment: Can you try to import the gql from "graphql-tag"? Actually its from 'apollo-boost'.
`import gql from "graphql-tag"`

Comment: Also, try:
`const link = new HttpLink({
  uri: 'http://localhost:4000/graphql'
})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is actual working. I was testing behind a proxy. I think it was a proxy issue.